# Which is faster: Loading images from the repo, or loading them using ACF Image Content via Media Library

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, media-library, performance

I have two methods of loading images in my mind right now:

1 - I store an image in a folder within my repo, and load it as a background image, defining it statically in CSS/Inline CSS.

2 - I store an image in the WordPress Media Library, upload it to an Image Content field within Advanced Custom Fields, and then load the src using inline styles in the template.

Which of these is faster?

My mind is telling me #1 because I don't have to go and get the img url from the uploads folder as directed by ACF, which is stored in the database but equally I don't know WordPress that well, so I might be wrong.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on the speed of your WP server (the database server specifically) and also the speed of the external repository. A database call to get the image URL isn't typically going to take long, but if you're on shared hosting or your database is bloated, it could slow things down. However, loading an image from a completely separate site causes a different HTTP request, which can also be slower than pulling everything from the same domain. So, to really compare the performance of these two options, you would have to do some benchmark testing with your specific servers.

Comment: Typically, best practice says to store everything in WordPress, rather than external sites. This may help end users better understand where everything is coming from, and using WordPress-specific functions tends to be less brittle than calling out to separate sites where APIs and availability may change.